# Association rules sorting in R

Tags: r, sorting, arules

Sorting the rules by lift or confidence is,

```
> rules.sorted <- sort(rules, by="lift")
```

But is it possible to sort by two or three columns (i.e., sort by lift,confidence and support(in this order))? In `order()`, we can sort based on any number of columns using comma. How to use that in `sort()` in `arules` package in R?

If I try this, I getting an following error,

```
 > rules.sorted <- sort(rules, by=c("lift","confidence","support"))
 > Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

**EDIT:**
You can find the process in following link http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/association-rules

Comment: can you include a small reproductible example?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I included the link, which contains all the steps. In that link, they sorted by lift alone, but i want to sort by lift, confidence and support values.

Comment: Turn rules to data frame and then sort it as usual. 
rules.df <- as(rules, "data.frame")

Comment: Just for the record: To quantify the information content of a rule, you can add a column with a rule evaluation measure (like the J-measure) and sort the rules according to that.